# Can ECMP be used with RIP?

Tags: rip, ecmp

I haven't seen anything about ECMP in the RIPv2 RFC.

Is it possible to use ECMP with RIP?

Comment: That depends on the vendor. For example, you can do that with Cisco by using the `maximum-paths` command.

Comment: RIP likely requires customizing the path costs to match the routes from other sources. If that's possible ECMP should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is not part of the RFC, some vendors support ECMP with RIP. For example, Cisco supports ECMP with RIP by using the `maximum-paths` command.

Other vendors may or may not support ECMP with RIP. For example, some (off-topic) consumer-grade routers can use RIP, but I have not seen any that can do ECMP.

You need to check with your router vendor to see if your router supports it.